# Why can't I modify an object after animating it?

Tags: wpf, animation

After executing this code...

```
DoubleAnimation a = new DoubleAnimation(newWidth, new Duration(...));
ThicknessAnimation b = new ThicknessAnimation(new Thickness(...), new Duration(...));
border.BeginAnimation(Border.MarginProperty, b);
border.BeginAnimation(Border.WidthProperty, a);
```

...this code no longer works (Margin does not change after assigning a new value):

```
// doesn't have any effect
border.Margin = new Thickness(...);
```

What's going on?? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Dependency Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx):

> Dependency properties can be animated.
>   When an animation is applied and is
>   running, the animated value operates
>   at a higher precedence than any value
>   (such as a local value) that the
>   property otherwise has.

You'll need to set the animation's FillBehavior to Stop for the local value to take precedence.